# Are there better ways of moving elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new here i did 1 basic website, using only HTML and CSS, which looked pretty bad, i gave the folder containing the code to a friend and when he opened index.html, some pictures were not positioned on his PC like it was positioned on my PC, i believe it has something to do with the resolution..

I used this code whenever i wanted to position an element or a picture:-

```
.class{
position:absolute/relative;
top: X px;
right: X px;
}
```

so my question is here, does the element's or picture affect that i am using this method to position ? are there better ways of positioning ?

Comment: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: There are many ways to position elements. I suggest you to find tutorials on internet and experience it yourself.